# Nodejs linux watch command like functionality

Tags: node.js, terminal, tty

What are the ways to implement linux's `watch` command functionality using Node.js?

When terminal stdout is replacing its content periodically? So I definitely **don't need** https://github.com/chjj/blessed capabilities. Just update/replace text content.

Should be a popular task, strange but couldn't google a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_cursorto_stream_x_y in combination with https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_clearscreendown_stream